# How to shorten this isset value check?

Tags: php, parameters

This is my first post. I hope I'm doing this right. I have written this little piece of code, it checks some request parameters. Has anyone a clue how to write this in a shorter and maybe better performance way?

```
$request = $_REQUEST;
if ( isset($request['customerId']) && 
    ! $request['customerId']  == '' && 
     isset($request['subscriptionId']) && 
     ! $request['subscriptionId']  == '' && 
     isset($request['customer_ext_uid']) && 
     ! $request['customer_ext_uid']  == '' && 
     isset($request['referrer']) && 
     ! $request['referrer']  == '' && 
     $request['referrer']  == 'fastbill' || 
     $request['referrer']  == 'paypal' && 
     $request['do']  == 'success' && 
     $request['do']  == 'success' ) :
    echo "good";
else :
    echo "bad";
endif;
```

In the end the success URL should look like this:

https://DOMAIN/?customerId=12347&customer_ext_uid=12347&subscriptionId=12347&referrer=paypal&do=success

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you can change all of the `isset(x) && ! x == ''` to `! empty(x)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do it could be like this, it'll also make it easier to add more checks in the future, and / or reuse it.

```
$required = array('customerID','subscriptionId'); //Fill in the fields you want checked
$request = $_REQUEST;

function allOk($required,$request){
    foreach($required as $key){
        if(empty($request[$key])){
            return FALSE;
            die();
        }
    }

    if($request['do'] != 'success' || ($request['referrer'] != 'fastbill' && $request['referrer'] != 'paypal')){
        return FALSE;
        die();
    }

    return TRUE;
}
```

And then you can either use  a if sentence or a ternary operator, depending how much action you want according to the result.

```
if(allOk($required,$request)){
   echo "good!";
}else{
   echo "BAD!";
}
```

Ternary operator:

```
echo (allOk($required,$request)) ? 'good' : 'bad' ;
```

Comment: This looks promising. Thanks in advance, i'll try it!

Comment: it still says BAD! when i use this parameter: https://DOMAIN/?customerId=1&customer_ext_uid=1&subscriptionId=1&referrer=paypal&do=success – but reading the code tells me it should be right. where could be the error?

Comment: Try now @PatrickDahm - changed the `||` to `&&` between `$request['referrer'] != 'fastbill' && $request['referrer'] != 'paypal'` and fixed a typo :)

Comment: @PatrickDahm If you got it working don't forget to click the little "Mark answer as accepted" :)

Comment: Dude, it works. Hell yeah, you did it. I mark it, thanks man. Nice to see that my first question is already solved! :)

Answer (score 2):

In the client side just create a new variable in a hiddenField and send this parameter to check.

Comment: Might be a solution, but not in my environment. But thanks for the advice!